# Credible intervals from bayesian NN misbehave

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, neural-networks, python, credible-interval

I am using [Edward](http://edwardlib.org/%22Edward%22), to create a Bayesian neural network for non-linear regression. My training set consists of time series that all end at 0 but after doing inference the predictions (and thus the credible intervals) do not seem to pick up on that i.e the network is not getting more confident as it approaches zero. The way I am generating my predictions and credible intervals is the following

```
n_of_preds = 200

xp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [Np, D])
y_post = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[Np,D])
A1 = neural_network_with_2_layers(xp,q_W_0, q_W_1,q_b_0, q_b_1)
A2 = tf.reshape(A1,[Np,1])
y_post = Normal(loc=A2,scale=q_sigma)

# Generating some outputs and averaging them
outputs = np.vstack([sess.run(y_post,{xp:X_test_norm}) for _ in range(n_of_preds)])
outputs = outputs.reshape([n_of_preds,X_test_norm.size])
p = np.average(outputs,0)

# De-normalization of the outputs using the train tests
dists = np.zeros(first_values_train.size,dtype=object)
for i in range(first_values_train.size):
    dists[i] = np.linalg.norm(first_values_train[i]-first_values_test)
dists.astype("float32")
min_dist_index = np.where(dists == np.min(dists))
Y_denorm = Y_train_max[min_dist_index]
p_denorm = ((p+1)/2)*Y_denorm

def Credible_intervals_from_predictions(predictions,credible_mass):
    ecdf = ECDF(predictions)
    z = ecdf.x
    w = ecdf.y
    w.astype("float32")
    w = np.around(w,decimals=3)
    # Find the index of w where w = 0.95/0.05 to know which values of z to keep
    u1 = np.where(w==credible_mass)
    a2 = 1 - credible_mass
    u2 = np.where(w==(np.around(a2,decimals=3)))
    # Upper and lower bounds of the interval
    UB = z[u1]
    LB = z[u2]
    return (LB,UB)

# Upper and lower bound for p (with q_sigma)
UB = np.zeros(outputs[0].size)
LB = np.zeros(outputs[0].size)
for i in range(outputs[0].size):
    LB[i],UB[i] = Credible_intervals_from_predictions(outputs[0:,i],0.95)
# De-norm them
UB = ((UB+1)/2)*Y_denorm
LB = ((LB+1)/2)*Y_denorm
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Added a figure

[image]